# How to fix specific PHP white screen error

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop

I know there's a lot about debugging PHP but I just cant seem to figure out why this bit of code doesn't work:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// CONNECT TO MYSQL
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","MySQLrootpass","cards");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "<div style='text-align: center;'>";
    echo "<h1>Could not connect to server, please try again later.</h1>";
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    echo "</div>";
}

$data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cards");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){ ?>
    <div id="card<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="cardPost" style="background-image: url('Sprites/card.png');" onClick="sideData('card','<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>')">
        <span class="cardTitle"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></span>
        <div class="elements">
            <img class="elmPic" src="Sprites/elms/<?php echo $row["element"]; ?>Elm.png">
        </div>
    </div>
<?php}

// DISCONNECT FORM MYSQL
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I'm new to the whole PHP display error thing, so I don't know why there not displaying.

After running it through a syntax checker, it said that the `}` at the end of the while loop was unexpected, I don't understand why, because this code worked fine until I added the id and onClick attribute to the `<div>`.
Now when I remove them it still doesn't work.

Also, I know it is this while loop, because when I comment it, all works well.
I also have another on the page just like this one (with the id and onClick) that works just fine.

One more thing, when I remove a semicolon in this second while loop (which starts off hidden), all works well still.

I know this is a very specific situation, but any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Maybe put a space at the last }, so it is <?php } instead of <?php}.  Does the script execute OK (instead of using the syntax checker)?

Comment: i jusk knew it was going to be somthing stupidly simple, thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I'm new to the whole php display error thing, so I don't know why there not displaying

`ini_set` and `error_reporting` are functions: like any other functions, they are executed when your script runs.  If your script has a parse error, it will never run in the first place, so your functions won't have a chance to do anything.

You can change these settings in your php.ini file instead, which will allow them to take effect before the script executes (and then you'll be able to see the error messages).

```
display_errors = on
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

> After running it through a syntax checker, it said that the } at the end of the while loop was unexpected, I don't understand why

There should be whitespace between `<?php` and `}`.

Answer (score 0):

As traq said, the problem is withespace between `<?php` and `}` (line 22). check this out:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// CONNECT TO MYSQL
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","ads");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "<div style='text-align: center;'>";
    echo "<h1>Could not connect to server, please try again later.</h1>";
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    echo "</div>";
}

$data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cards");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){ ?>
    <div id="card<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="cardPost" style="background-image: url('Sprites/card.png');" onClick="sideData('card','<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>')">
        <span class="cardTitle"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></span>
        <div class="elements">
            <img class="elmPic" src="Sprites/elms/<?php echo $row["element"]; ?>Elm.png">
        </div>
    </div>
<?php }

// DISCONNECT FORM MYSQL
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
ini_set('display_errors','1');  // value in quotes
```

For special people. Visit this link .
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ini-set.php

If not works then.

```
 <?php  

     phpinfo();  
     /*
     find where is php.ini
     then tell admin to change if you dont have permissions.
    */


 ?>
```

Also you can try [error_get_last](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.error-get-last.php)

Comment: SyntaxLAMP solved my problom, but thanks for the reply anyways

Comment: I don't know who set minus to my answer.
Explain me why did you do that .

Comment: I am not the person who downvoted you, but here's a possible explanation: this doesn't answer the OP's question. If you had tested this, you would have found that both `1` and `"1"` produce the same result (as would "On" or "true" or "yes"; [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)).